# Cassandra Datastax C# Driver, all Unittest of the VS solution Cassandra.sln failed

Tags: ssh, cassandra

I have taken the branch 1.0 source code of the Cassandra Datastax C# Driver and tried to study the code. The VS solution cassandra.sln does compile OK but all the 3 Unittest projects run failed. 
I have found that the methodes of the unittest use 2 IP addr, one is the localhost:9042 and one is: 192.168.13.1:22. The later uses 22 as the SSH port.
Can anybody help me:
1. How to configure Cassandra on Windows with the port 22 as the SSH port with an user & password? I do not get any document about that.

I guess that is the cause that all the unittest of the VS solution cassandra.sln are failed.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I had to tackle that same problem recently.  At the time, it was *definitely impossible* to run unit tests without involving a non-Windows (== Linux) machine in the setup. This *may* no longer be the case today; see the note at the very bottom.

With that in mind this is what I had to do:

1. Stand up a Linux host on the same LAN, if you don't have one already
2. Install software called [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) on the Linux host
3. Use `ifconfig` to create several IP aliases on the Linux host, such that the host is reachable from outside using those IPs.  I believe I had to create 6 or more aliases to cover all unit tests (some unit tests use that many instances of Cassandra at the same time when emulating a cluster).
4. Configure the firewall to enable ports 9160 for all those aliases (in my case, I disabled the firewall entirely when running unit tests). The aliases have to follow a certain pattern for UT harness to be able to connect; see 6c).
5. Ensure that sshd is installed, running and accessible on the Linux host.
6. Back on Windows, edit gotest.bat and modify:

   a) login credentials to enable you to successfully log into the Linux host

   b) `-h` parameter to point to your Linux host IP

   c) `-i` parameter to match your Linux aliases.  When setting up your aliases, make sure you use addresses `a.b.c.x`, where `x` goes from 1 to whatever your highest alias is.  For example the default value of `-i 192.168.13` in `gotest.bat` means that the test framework expects host aliases to be 192.168.13.1, 192.168.13.2, 192.168.13.3 and so on.

And after that, if I remember correctly, I could run unit tests.  I am writing this answer partially from memory, so I may have missed something; add a comment below if you run into trouble.

NOTE: a few weeks ago `ccm` added Windows support.  Therefore, you should be able to run the cluster on Windows.  Whether you can run unit tests completely on Windows is an open question, as the UT harness uses SSH to connect to the cluster and stand up/tear down various cluster configurations.  Furthermore, because Windows support is so fresh, there may still be bugs unrelated to the C# driver that you could be running into.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Daniel

Since I am evaluating the Db Cassandra vs. other choice (SQL and NoSQL Dbs), proposed by my collegues so I must recongnize this actual problem of Cassandra as one of its Minus-point in the evaluation result table when we compare it with other Db:

IMHO Cassandra is a good NoSQL Db for (Linuy & Java people) and conditionally good for Windows & C# plattforms.

Are there some commercial C# driver for Cassandra that deliver Unittest running OK ?